# Mongodb: updating a variable field name

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to add a new field with a variable name to an object in the DB : meaning, I don't know the name of the field, but it's held in a variable "newFieldName".

So what I want to do is basically this:

```
var newFieldName = "world";
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 3 },
   { $set: {
             "hello."+newFieldName: "Amazing Grace"
           }
   }
)
```

After the update, I expect the object "hello" to have a field "world" with the value "Amazing Grace".

but this doesn't even compile, let alone work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an intermediary object:

```
var update = { $set : {} };
update.$set['hello.' + newFieldName] = 'Amazing Grace';
db.bios.update({ _id : 3 }, update, ...)
```

Comment: @yossale don't think so :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var some_object = Posts.findOne({...});
var new_value = 1337;

Posts.update(another_object._id,
    {$set: {
        [some_object.some_field]:new_value,
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You should provide some context and explanatory text around the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To answer @yossale & @robertklep, the inline version is in fact possible using an expression and the comma operator:

```
var newFieldName = "world", o;
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 3 },
   {$set:(o = {}, o["hello."+newFieldName] = "Amazing Grace", o)}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple is that:

```
var newFieldName = "world";
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 3 },
   { $set: {
             ["hello."+newFieldName]: "Amazing Grace"
           }
   }
);
```

@Andy's answer solved my problem.

Comment: The `[ variable ]` expression is super; never knew about that until now.